# When writing a tool named "foo", why symlink PROJECT/bin/foo to ../libexec/foo

Tags: symlink

I've been learning bash and unix by reading source code.

This particular bit I don't understand why it was done.

The main tool executable is a symbolic link. Whats the benefit here?

[image]

[source](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/tree/master/bin)

Answer (score 0):

In the case of a multi-call binary, like kmod calls itself, the idea provide a simple user interface - some options less.

man kmod says: "Most users will only run it using its other names."

```
$  ls ??mod ???mod modprobe kmod -l
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  63496 Mar 11  2019 chmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Feb 13  2019 depmod -> kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Feb 13  2019 insmod -> kmod
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 161856 Feb 13  2019 kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Feb 13  2019 lsmod -> kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Feb 13  2019 modprobe -> kmod
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root      4 Feb 13  2019 rmmod -> kmod
```

In your example, it means: there is one big executable/library, not the "usual" `bin/exec` plus `some/lib/library`. So just use any symlink to call it. Or rather: use a symlink `rbenv` from anywhere. Makes certain aspects of developing easier I guess.